# Why doesn't this work on Chrome alone?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

This is my site : http://searchr.us/

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQKTS.png
```

When i click on that.Firefox and Internet Explorer give the option whether or no to make searchr.us the default search engine but not in Chrome.Nothing happens in chrome.

Can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: What have you done to make it the default?

Comment: Please rephrase your title - it's evil. And the question ha nothing to do with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Chrome does not have an actual search bar?

It lets you add the site as search engine, and assign it a keyword to use it from the address bar. If you want to use a different search engine for any non-link in the address bar, you will have to change it manually from the preferences.

Comment: Oh so i can't do with programming ?